# Provider org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.JpaIntegrator not found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I inherited a multi-module system with the ancient dependencies of Hibernate and Spring. I was trying to refresh (So far, I managed to get to versions 5.4.9 and 4.3.20, respectively) they ran into a problem:

```
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.JpaIntegrator not found
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:372)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedServiceLoader$ClassPathOnlyAggregatedServiceLoader.getAll(AggregatedServiceLoader.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:251)
    at org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(IntegratorServiceImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:224)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.getMetadataSources(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:364)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1688)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1626)
    ... 46 more
```

The project is being built and starts to run.
How to get rid of this problem?

Nothing really changed even after changing the spring and hibernate versions to the following:

```
springVersion = '5.1.6.RELEASE'
hibernateVersion = '5.4.2.Final'
```

Now the stack trace looks like this:

```
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.JpaIntegrator not found
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:372)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedServiceLoader$ClassPathOnlyAggregatedServiceLoader.getAll(AggregatedServiceLoader.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:251)
    at org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(IntegratorServiceImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:224)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.getMetadataSources(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:442)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
    ... 48 more
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.3/migration-guide.adoc#jpaintegrator-removed) it is said that the class "org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.JpaIntegrator" is simply removed from the library.

Therefore, to eliminate this exception, you must:
either delete the file "org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator" from the project that refers to this class and catch new fleas;
either implement the "org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator" interface yourself and put a link to this class in the "org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator" file.